# Magento 2 how to disable 'add new address' button from customer address book page, in account section?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, customer-address

I want to disable 'add new address' button from customer account address book and customer account section with checking if my custom module is - enable/disable.

file name is :
`vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\address\book.phtml`

how can I override it and disable the button and edit/delete address link also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the layout file in your module.

from:

> vendor\magento\module-customer\view\layout\customer_address_index.xml

To

> Name\Module\view\frontend\layout\customer_address_index.xml

then override phtml file in your module
from

> vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\address\book.phtml

To

> Name\Module\view\frontend\templates\address\book.phtml

and do the needful changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `book.phtml` file in your current theme on below path and comment the required code.

```
app/design/frontend/DESIGN_PACKAGE/THEME_NAME/Magento_Customer/templates/address/book.phtml
```

Comment: I want this thing with module. not with theme.